# Problem with baseurl and interaction with plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have built a plug in and it appears to hook in ok.  It runs at least.  However it loads very slowly. I have attached my console log results.  It appears as though the base url is not correctly built in some cases.  www.mydomain.com/wordpress/plugin is combining with /wp-includes/js/jquery/.  These entries should be www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/.  I am also seeing that this is inconsistent, sometimes it is built just fine.  So I am trying to track down the file where this is happening but I am a little lost.  Any tips would help.

```
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 (index):54
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 404 (Not Found)  (index):55
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4    (index):603 
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4 404 (Not Found)  (index):604
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4  (index):606
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4  (index):608
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4   (index):607
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/button.min.js?ver=1.11.4  (index):609
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.3   (index):616
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/pluginjs/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3    (index):28
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4  (index):608 
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/button.min.js?ver=1.11.4 404 (Not Found)  (index):609
GET https://www.example.com/wordpress/plugin/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.3 404 (Not Found)   (index):616
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tinyNav is not a function(…)    TinyNav.js?ver=4.5.3:91
Google sync successful  frontend_book.js:513
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problem was resolved by pasting the following into my functions.php

```
     function my_init()   
{  
    if (!is_admin())   
    {  
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');  

        // Load the copy of jQuery that comes with WordPress  
        // The last parameter set to TRUE states that it should be loaded  
        // in the footer.  
        wp_register_script('jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', FALSE, '1.11.4', TRUE);  

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
    }  
}  
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you enqueue/register these files ? Do you try to enqueue them like your file or treat them as dépendances ?

To use any file from the WordPress core registered-scripts library, you only need to register them and set dependancies your plugin require with `wp_register_script` (trigger with wp_enqueue_scripts action).

You will find the list of all core-registered scripts [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)

> Scripts that have been pre-registered using wp_register_script() do not need to be manually enqueued using wp_enqueue_script() if they are listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued. WordPress will automatically include the registered script before it includes the enqueued script that lists the registered script’s handle as a dependency.